# Sci-fi novel: alien planet experiencing plague, stimulates avant-garde art in doomed populace

Tags: story-identification, novel, post-apocalyptic, art

I must have read this book in the '90s or earlier.

There's an entire planet quarantined, as lots of people die off. Instead of the standard post-apocalypse story, it's about how people cope with their mortality by partying and participating in an artistic renaissance.

I remember a scene where a woman in a pub performs a conceptual art piece where she bleeds everywhere, confronting the culture's newfound hemophobia and sanitary taboos.

I seem to recall that there's AI personalities involved. And maybe the author is female.

Basically, it's a sort of alien-world riff off the social/economic changes triggered by the Black Death in medieval Europe.

Needless to say, current events often bring this story to mind.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If you have time, please take a look at the check lists in [this thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), and then [edit] your question to include any more details that you can think to add. The more info you can provide about the novel (the appearance of the cover, for example), the greater the chance that someone can ID it for you. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [*Memento Mori*](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Memento_Mori.html?id=l1aSPwAACAAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y) by Shariann Lewitt

> Once a glittering center of arts and culture, the colony world of Reis is being ravaged by an unchecked plague. As anarchy, cynicism and suspicion spread, a handful of the planet's young artists struggle to keep hope alive, clashing in a deadly game of wits with the seductive artificial intelligence that has taken control of their world--and their minds.
>
> [image]

I found this by using the advanced search on Amazon. It was the first "Plague" keyword book to show up with a publication date before 1996.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing in a blurb to explain how this matches the description in the original question.